# Moment of inertia of sphere

Tags: physics

I know that the moment of inertia of a sphere is $\frac{2}{5}mr^2$ but using the perpendicular axis theorem we can get that the $I_z=I_x+I_y$ and they are all equal in case of the sphere because of its symmetry, therefore $I = I + I$ and then $I=0$! Isn't that wrong?

Comment: Perhaps this is better asked on the physics stack exchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [perpendicular axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpendicular_axis_theorem) can be only used to determine the moment of inertia of a rigid object that lies entirely within a plane.  And a sphere does not.